# Javascript onkeypress

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a question regarding the `onkeypress` event on JavaScript.

Is it possible to detect just <kbd>Cntl</kbd> key or <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key? At the moment if both <kbd>Cntl</kbd> and <kbd>m</kbd> are pressed the `onkeypress` event can trigger a click. Is it possible to do just <kbd>Cntl</kbd> key by itself?

Looking forward to your comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onkeypress` just catches character keys. Use `onkeydown` and/or `onkeyup` for the other keys. See [Peter-Paul Koch on key events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html).

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, no, you can't just capture the Ctrl key. [The hotkeys jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/) which focuses exclusively on capturing keys doesn't capture the straight "Ctrl" key either, so I'm guessing it's not possible. [You can catch it with the mouse events](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/ctrl_alt.htm), but that's not quite the same thing.

http://jshotkeys.googlepages.com/test-static-01.html