# How to add javascript function to Textbox control at OnKeypress

Tags: javascript, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript onkeypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929729/javascript-onkeypress)

I have many page in my site. (using dot.net)

I have written one onKeypress event function in javascript, which should be used by all of my textboxes (in total site).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Look harder. There are plenty of answers to this question in this site already.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for a keydown event.
here's a library available on GitHub

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

```
$(expression).bind(types, keys, handler);
$(expression).unbind(types, handler);

$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+a', fn);

// e.g. replace '$' sign with 'EUR'
$('input.foo').bind('keyup', '$', function(){
  this.value = this.value.replace('$', 'EUR');
});
```